# Tutorials for shadow mapping with multiple point lights in XNA

Tags: c#, xna, lighting, shadow-mapping

I've been trying to crack this problem for a while now and I'd like to know if there's a tutorial or two out there that can help me with this.  I know how to do shadow mapping with a single light, and I know how to implement multiple lights.  What I can't seem to do is put them together, despite my many attempts.

So yeah, does anyone know of any XNA tutorials that can baby-step me through this?

EDIT: This is for a 3D environment

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is, but [here is one for DirectX](http://rastertek.com/dx10tut41.html).

But since your problem is that yours is not working, I would suggest writing as much information as you can to console, and building some tools to show what is going on, [like a draw line function](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/23140/drawing-a-one-pixel-wide-line-in-3d-space). Personally, I like to copy my entire project folder every couple hours when doing this sort of thing. Best of luck.

edit: I've added some links in the comments. Hopefully there is something you can use there.

Comment: Also [Remers Tutorial](http://www.riemers.net/eng/Tutorials/XNA/Csharp/Series3/Shadow_map.php) ([This form thread](http://www.riemers.net/Forum/index.php?var=1206&var2=0) suggests this may not be your best bet, but mentions a book that may help)

Comment: [Shadow Mapping Example](http://xbox.create.msdn.com/en-US/education/catalog/sample/shadow_mapping_1) and [it's related tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb975671(v=xnagamestudio.31).aspx) (I've noticed some weird artifacts in this one, depending on the camera position)

Comment: [Someone with a similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9660959/how-to-use-a-single-shadow-map-for-multiple-point-light-sources)

Comment: [An OpenGL Tutorial](http://www.opengl-tutorial.org/intermediate-tutorials/tutorial-16-shadow-mapping/) it's pretty in depth.

Comment: [A list of HLSL tutorials](http://xboxforums.create.msdn.com/forums/t/27849.aspx)

Comment: [One last DirectX tutorial](http://takinginitiative.net/2011/05/15/directx10-tutorial-10-shadow-mapping/)

Comment: [Some debugging tips](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/17155/debugging-tips)

Answer (score 0):

This tutorial should explain to you how to accomplish this:

http://www.catalinzima.com/2010/07/my-technique-for-the-shader-based-dynamic-2d-shadows/

I've used this technique and it works quite well.

Comment: Sorry bro.  Forgot to mention that this was in a 3D environment